# ListCell with editable ListView as graphic: ClassCastException on commitEdit

Tags: listview, javafx

In JavaFx v17, JDK v17, Maven, IntelliJ:
A Listview<TokenWord> (=TOKListView) is in each row of a Listview<Signification> (=SIGListView). When I am editing a cell of the TOKListView I make a commitEdit() call in the startEdit() section, then I get an Error `class TokenWord cannot be cast to class Signification`. The SIGListView should not, but will do an updateItem(), but why?

Main.class // ReprEx

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class);
    }

    public class Signification {
        ArrayList<TokenWord> tokenWords;

        public Signification(ArrayList<TokenWord> tokenWords) {
            this.tokenWords = tokenWords;
        }

        public ArrayList<TokenWord> getTokenWords() {
            return tokenWords;
        }
    }

    public class TokenWord {
        String Text;

        public TokenWord(String text) {
            Text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return Text;
        }
    }

    final ListView<Signification> significationListView = new ListView<>();

    final ArrayList<Signification> significations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        significations.add(
                new Signification(new ArrayList<TokenWord>(Arrays.asList(
                        new TokenWord("One")
                ))));


        significationListView.setCellFactory(significationListView -> {
            ListCell<Signification> siCell = new ListCell<Signification>() {

                //PROBLEM AREA ---- START --------------------------------------
                //########## PROBLEM CONSUMED (of PROBLEM FIRED see below) #########
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Signification sigItem, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(sigItem, empty);
                    if ((!empty) && (sigItem != null)) {

                        ListView<TokenWord> tokenWordListView = new ListView<TokenWord>();
                        tokenWordListView.setEditable(true);
                        tokenWordListView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

                        tokenWordListView.setCellFactory(twListView -> {

                            //  each Cell a new Listview
                            ListCell<TokenWord> twCell = new ListCell<TokenWord>() {

                                @Override
                                public void updateItem(TokenWord twItem, boolean empty) {
                                    super.updateItem(twItem, empty);
                                    if ((!empty) && (twItem != null)) setText(twItem.getText());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void startEdit() {
                                    if (!isEditable() || !getListView().isEditable()) return;
                                    super.startEdit();
                                    if (isEditing()) {
                                        setText("");
                                        TextField textField = new TextField(getItem().getText());
                                        textField.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {

                                            //########## PROBLEM FIRED ###########
                                            commitEdit(new TokenWord(textField.getText()));
                                        });
                                        setGraphic(textField);
                                    } else setGraphic(null);
                                }
                            };

                            return twCell;
                        });
                        tokenWordListView.getItems().addAll(sigItem.getTokenWords());
                        setGraphic(tokenWordListView);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
                //PROBLEM AREA ---- END --------------------------------------

            };

            siCell.setPrefHeight(40);

            return siCell;
        });

        significationListView.getItems().addAll(significations);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(significationListView), 400, 150));

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Errormessage:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.example.TheApp$TokenWord cannot be cast to class org.example.TheApp$Signification (org.example.TheApp$TokenWord and org.example.TheApp$Signification are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.example.TheApp$1.updateItem(TheApp.java:61)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:481)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.lambda$new$2(ListCell.java:168)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:239)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:211)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.set(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:170)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView.lambda$new$1(ListView.java:375)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.commitEdit(ListCell.java:390)
    at org.example.TheApp$1$1.lambda$startEdit$0(TheApp.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:154)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.lambda$keyMapping$62(TextInputControlBehavior.java:332)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4105)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2156)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2630)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:548)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:972)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.example.TheApp$TokenWord cannot be cast to class org.example.TheApp$Signification (org.example.TheApp$TokenWord and org.example.TheApp$Signification are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.example.TheApp$1.updateItem(TheApp.java:61)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:481)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.indexChanged(ListCell.java:337)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1807)
    at javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.addTrailingCells(VirtualFlow.java:2191)
    at javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1327)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1207)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1214)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:579)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2515)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: "Why and how to prevent updateItem" -> There is no good reason to prevent the call, so how to do it is irrelevant.  What is your actual problem?  Focus on what you are trying to achieve and the root cause that is preventing that from occurring.  Then ask about that instead of coming up with an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as a work-around.

Comment: please work through a tutorial on how to use cells to understand what should/not be done in its updateItem (it's strictly about configuring _its own visuals_ - nothing else), then apply what you learned to your context. When stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected.

Comment: @jewelsea, in my logical understanding the updatecall should only work on the TOKListview and not on the SIGListView. In SIGListView is nothing changing after I changed the cell of the TOKListView.
I only want to change the item of the TOKListview, but now there is a updateItemCall on the SIGListView and I don't know why.
How would you write the title of this topic?

Comment: @kleopatra thx for your comment, but I don't know what tutorial you mean? With this minimal code you are able to get the same error I also get.

Comment: _With this minimal code you are able to get the same error_ no, it doesn't even compile (due to imports of unrelated and basically unneeded classes, f.i. the annotations or your custom data) repeating: [mcve] required - _I don't know what tutorial you mean_ choose an arbitrary - pretty sure there is none that adds data logic in the updateItem (if you stumbled across such, use another :)

Comment: Get rid of all the Lombok nonsense. It almost never makes sense to use that in a real application anyway, imho.

Comment: "How would you write the title of this topic?" -> I wouldn't.  I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.  See the xy problem link and other comments for suggestions on how to improve the question.

Comment: To answer the title question portion: "how to prevent updateItem call in Listview" -> updateItem will be triggered when the cell value changes.  For example, you scroll, resize or reorder the list view, or you modify the backing list by adding, removing, or reordering a value or change the value of an extracted property of the list.  To prevent an update, don't do any of these things: don't scroll, reorder or resize the list and don't update the backing list or properties of observed objects in the backing list.  I have a feeling though that this information doesn't actually help you much.

Comment: @kleopatra, now it should be compiling 100%.

Comment: @jewelsea exactly this is how I thought a listview is working. But I don't change any observed item in the listview of SIGListView. I only make a change on the TWListView and the SIGListView is trying to make an updateItem with the Item I supported to the TWListView.

Comment: thanks :) And can reproduce the error: seems to happen because the edit event bubbles up the event dispatch chain to the outer listView (which expects a signification, not a tokenword). To fix, set a custom onCommit handler that consumes the event after invoking the default handler.

Comment: .. and don't create nodes in updateItem (that's defeating the whole purpose of having cells :) - instead, do it upfront in the cell's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because editing is controlled via events and we have a ListView with a cell containing a ListView:

- a commit is delivered along the usual event dispatch chain
- the commit is fired from the editing cell (the one containing the textField) to the inner listView
- the default commit handler of the inner listView handles the event by saving the edited value
- then it bubbles up to the commit handler of the outer listView where it causes the class cast exception

The last happens because the default commit handler *does not* consume the event. The solution is to consume it.

Some code (for clarity extracted into a separate class, could just as well be done inline)

```
public class OuterCell extends ListCell<Signification> {
    ListView<TokenWord> tokenWordListView;
    {
        tokenWordListView = new ListView<TokenWord>();
        tokenWordListView.setEditable(true);
        tokenWordListView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        // grab default commit handler
        EventHandler<EditEvent<TokenWord>> handler = tokenWordListView.getOnEditCommit();
        tokenWordListView.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            // let default handler save the edited value
            handler.handle(t);
            // consume to prevent dispatching the event to the outer list
            t.consume();
        });

        // use TextFieldListCell for inner cell 
        StringConverter<TokenWord> converter = new StringConverter<>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(TokenWord token) {
                return token != null ? token.getText() : "";
            }

            @Override
            public TokenWord fromString(String string) {
                return new TokenWord(string);
            }

        };
        tokenWordListView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView(converter));
        setPrefHeight(40);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Signification sigItem, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(sigItem, empty);
        if ((!empty) && (sigItem != null)) {
            tokenWordListView.getItems().setAll(sigItem.getTokenWords());
            setGraphic(tokenWordListView);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

}
```